# Image Animation in Swift

Tags: swift

I some have code that animates two images, imageA & imageB. The code works how I want it to work, however I cant figure out how to end the animation. Any suggestions on how to end the animation or stop it from animating? Thanks :)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    let images = [
            UIImage(named: "imageB.png")!,
            UIImage(named: "imageA.png")!]
    var index = 0
    let animationDuration: NSTimeInterval = 0.25
    let switchingInterval: NSTimeInterval = 3

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            imageView.image = images[index++]
            animateImageView()
    }

    func animateImageView() {
            CATransaction.begin()

            CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(animationDuration)
            CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
                    let delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(self.switchingInterval * NSTimeInterval(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
                    dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            self.animateImageView()
                    }
            }

            let transition = CATransition()
            transition.type = kCATransitionFade

            imageView.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
            imageView.image = images[index]

            CATransaction.commit()

            index = index < images.count - 1 ? index + 1 : 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to execute your animation just one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some changes in your code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

let images = [
    UIImage(named: "ImageB")!,
    UIImage(named: "ImageA")!]
var index = 0
let animationDuration: NSTimeInterval = 0.25
let switchingInterval: NSTimeInterval = 3

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //next line changed to start from first image in array
    imageView.image = images[index]
    animateImageView()
}


func animateImageView() {
    CATransaction.begin()

    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(animationDuration)
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {[weak self] in
        if let strongSelf = self {
            //check if there are more images to display
            if strongSelf.index < strongSelf.images.count {
                let delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(strongSelf.switchingInterval * NSTimeInterval(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
                dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    strongSelf.animateImageView()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade

    imageView.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    imageView.image = images[index]

    CATransaction.commit()
    //increment index
    index++
}
}
```

- It will start with the first position of the array in viewDidLoad.
- It will call animateImageView if still there are more image left in the array. So, if you add more images in the array it will display all of them once.
- Changed the increment in animateImageView to not cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code to stop the `CATransaction`:

```
CATransaction.setDisableActions = true
```